# Is a private list object being accessed by a public method causing a problem?

Tags: apex, permissions

I have a nightly build process that sends messages based on the status of a case. It just started erroring out in production, but doesn't break in sandboxes.

There is a message list object defined at the top of the class before defining methods.

```
private List<EmailMessage> messageList = new List<EmailMessage>();
```

I then have a public method that adds messages to that list.

```
    public void addEmailMessage(ID recipient, Case c, string template, string templateId){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, recipient, c.Id);
    string toAddress;
    
    EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
    em.RelatedToId = c.Id;
    em.Subject = 'Email: ' + template;
    em.FromAddress = 'myemail@mycompany.com';
    em.HtmlBody = mail.getHtmlBody();

    //check to either owner or contact
    em.ToAddress = recipient;
    messageList.add(em);
```

I have a loop of cases (cs) that goes through all my cases and adds to the message list.

```
addEmailMessage(cs.ContactId, cs, 'CaseFound',emailTemplateMap.get('CaseClosedTemplate'));
```

I'm getting errors on the addEmailMessage in the loop

"*Attempt to de-refrence a null object Class.NightlyCaseBatch.addEmailMessage*"

If I change messageList from private to public will this fix this issue? Also, why would it work in sandbox but not in prod?

Comment: The quick answer is that the `private` visibility modifier is not causing your issue here (and changing it to `public` would not help). Please [edit] your question to add the stack trace for your error. Best guess at this point is that someone fiddled around with your email templates (in production but not in any sandboxes).

Comment: Email templates is a great suggestion... investigating...

Comment: @DerekF Great catch there. I was about to say that. Its definitely not the public /private visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be this line of code

```
//check to either owner or contact
em.ToAddress = recipient;
```

EmailMessage.ToAddress has to be a string. I was sending in an ID. What's bizarre is that if I ran the Apex Anonymously through the Dev Console it worked, but when it ran on the nightly build it threw an error. Since the recipient was already added in the renderStoredEmailTemplate

```
mail = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, recipient, c.Id);
```

Adding the recipient to the ToAddress was redundant as well as the wrong variable assignment.